# Chrome extension settings/flags API access for dark mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am a browser extension developer and want to access the Chrome browser users default setting for dark-mode. Specifically the setting for chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark

I have a background-script and content-script running in the extension and wonder if I can get the default dark-mode setting there.

Also I would need this setting for Firefox if available.